# Up to date documentation for faveo-helpdesk plugin creation

Tags: laravel-5

I'm searching for an updated doc for faveo-helpdesk (based on Laravel) plugin development, but it looks like the current github links are out of date. Following instructions described seems not working even for very basic plugin with the mininum required files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are makers of Faveo Helpdesk. We haven't really worked on Community version for a while now, as our team has been occupied with Pro version. We are planning to make a release of Faveo Community this month with Laravel 5.6 upgrade. You can discuss with us on Skype, what you are looking for and we can help you.